# Multi Indexed in Collection with O(1) searching time

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary, indexing, in-memory

Suppose I want to make one Collection of Class which have 10 properties, This collection holds about 10 million items.

Now I want to search this collection with O(1) time complexity or near to O(1) by any property of Class.(Not by only one property i.e ID or Name)

If I use List than it by LINQ query it will require O(n) time complexity, So it can't be used.

C# have dictionary which can be indexed by only one key type. So it also can't be used.

As one solution I can make 10 Dictionaries indexed with every property, but this solution will require large amount of memory as it has 10 million items. So it would be not feasible.

P.S. I want only in memory solution (No database) and the collection can be searched by any single property of class (eg. MyCollection[2] or MyCollection["John"] or MyCollection["12/12/2013"] etc) and the searching time must be near to O(1).

So how can I implement this kind of data structure??

Comment: You are aware that 10 properties, let's say they're `int`s and fields for easier calculation, so 4 bytes each, times 1 billion will put you in ~40 GB memory range, right? And that's items alone, without any kind of container for them...

Comment: 1 billion records in memory ??? really ?

Comment: I have doubts that this is possible considering that databases generally _do_ create extra data structures "indices" to improve search on different columns (which are conceptually equivalent to your properties). Also, do you really want to store 1 billion items in memory? That's a lot of memory

Comment: `OrderedDictionary` ? but it is non generic

Comment: Lets say 10 million, I was providing data only for example

Comment: Each "key" is going to require a separate index. Ultimately, the only O(1) solution will be 10 separate dictionaries, with appropriate hash functions.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That has the exact same problem as a `Dictionary`.  You only get one key per dictionary.

Comment: @GlitchMaybe If you only have 10 million then why can't you create 10 dictionaries?  That's not *that* much memory.

Comment: @GlitchMaybe You could also take a look at [B+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) [trees](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/btree_package.html), since those are the trees commonly used in databases, but I can't really say much more as I have never implemented one of those. Also, retrieval will be rather `O(logn)` than `O(1)`, but with that many items in a regular dictionary you usually have a high probability of hash collisions and degradation of performance from the starting `O(1)`.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek The primary advantage of such a tree is that they can be effectively serialized onto a file, since a DB can't keep indexes in memory all of the time.  Since the OP is going to have enough memory to not need to swap them out to disk he doesn't need to resort to that.

Comment: @Servy You have a point. I'm just trying to cover all the bases and throwing ideas out there :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.  You need to make a trade of between memory or time.  Either create your 10 different indexes (i.e. 10 internal dictionaries) to get O(1) lookup time or do linear searches to prevent any increase in the memory footprint.

Those are your choices.  There is no magic bullet that gives you the best of both here.